# How to display 2 if statement at the same time JAVA

Tags: java, loops, if-statement

```
private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener
  {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
         if(checkboxcheck1 == 1)
            {
             textFieldSum.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
            }
         else if (checkboxcheck2 == 1)
         {
              textFieldSum1.setText(String.valueOf(counter1));
         }

         else
             {
              checkboxcheck1 = 0;
             }
    }
```

I create 2 check boxs and 1 button and 2 text fields. When I click on the check box and then click the button the text fields will show the result. I want to make button show the result if I clicked on 2 checkbox at the same time. Can somebody please help me. I think about write a loop but I dont know how to write it. Thanks yall so much for help.

Edit 1: This is all my code

```
public class Count extends JFrame
```

{

```
private JLabel labelSum = new JLabel("Display: ");

private JTextField textFieldSum = new JTextField(1);

private JCheckBox chckbxNewCheckBox1 = new JCheckBox("A");

private JButton btnYes = new JButton("YES");

private JTextField textFieldSum1 = new JTextField(1);

private JCheckBox chckbxNewCheckBox2 = new JCheckBox("B");

private int counter;

private int counter1;

private int checkboxcheck1 = 0;

private int checkboxcheck2 = 0;

public Count()

{
    super("Yolo Coto");

    super.setBounds(150, 150, 500, 500);

    GridBagLayout gridBagLayout = new GridBagLayout();

    gridBagLayout.columnWidths = new int[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

    gridBagLayout.rowHeights = new int[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

    gridBagLayout.columnWeights = new double[]{0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};

    gridBagLayout.rowWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};

    super.getContentPane().setLayout(gridBagLayout);

    //checkbox

    add(chckbxNewCheckBox1);

    textFieldSum.setEditable(false);

    CheckBoxHandler handler = new CheckBoxHandler();

    chckbxNewCheckBox1.addItemListener(handler);

    //textfield

    add(textFieldSum);

    //button

    add(btnYes);

    ButtonHandler handler1 = new ButtonHandler();

    btnYes.addActionListener(handler1);


    //checkbox2

    add(chckbxNewCheckBox2);

    textFieldSum1.setEditable(false);

    chckbxNewCheckBox2.addItemListener(handler);

    //textfield2

    add(textFieldSum1);

    //readfile

    BufferedReader reader;

    int counterA = 0;

    int counterB = 0;

    try {

        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("in.txt"));

        int data;

        while ((data = reader.read()) != -1)

        {

            char charA = 'A';

            char charB = 'B';

           // char[] charArray = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E' };

            if (charA == (char) data) 

            {
                counterA++;
            }    

            if (charB == (char) data) 
            {
                counterB++;
            }     
        }
        counter1 = counterB;
        counter = counterA;
        reader.close();
    } 
    catch (IOException ioException) 
    {
        System.err.println("Error Opening File: Terminating");
        System.exit(1);
    }     
}     
  private class CheckBoxHandler implements ItemListener
    {
    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) 
    {
        if(chckbxNewCheckBox1.isSelected())
        {
            checkboxcheck1 = 1;

        }
        else if(chckbxNewCheckBox2.isSelected())
        {
            checkboxcheck2 = 1;
        }
        else if (chckbxNewCheckBox1.isSelected() && chckbxNewCheckBox2.isSelected())
        {
            checkboxcheck1 = 1;
            checkboxcheck2 = 1;
        }
    }
    }

  private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener
  {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
         if(checkboxcheck1 == 1)
            {
             textFieldSum.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
            }
         else if (checkboxcheck2 == 1)
         {
              textFieldSum1.setText(String.valueOf(counter1));
         }
         else if (checkboxcheck1 == 1 && checkboxcheck2 == 1)
         {
             textFieldSum.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
             textFieldSum1.setText(String.valueOf(counter1));
         }
         else
         {
            checkboxcheck1 = 0;
         }
    }
```

All I want is when I click both checkbox and click the button its show the result in the that textfield. Or I click on single check box and its still show the result in that single textfield. Because I have like 20 more check boxs in my real program. Basically, all I want is if I click on any checkbox and then click the button it will show the result.

Comment: you mean `if(checkboxcheck1 == 1 && checkboxcheck2 == 1)` ..

Comment: Can you post a reproducible amount of code? so we can come up with a solution/suggestion.

Comment: if this is Swing, you have to use `checkboxcheck1.isSelected()` also you just need to get rid of else if. put it as 2 separate if statements.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that two checkboxes must be clicked in order for the button to show then like this maybe?

```
private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener
  {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
         if(checkboxcheck1 == 1 && checkboxcheck2 == 1)
            {
             textFieldSum.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want an if statement with both conditions.  The && operator is what you want.

```
private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener
  {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
         if(checkboxcheck1 == 1)
            {
             textFieldSum.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
            }
         else if (checkboxcheck2 == 1)
         {
              textFieldSum1.setText(String.valueOf(counter1));
         }
         else if (checkboxcheck1 == 1 && checkboxcheck2 == 1)
         {
             //do something
         }
         else
         {
            checkboxcheck1 = 0;
         }
    }
```

Comment: I kinda want a method to do it because I have 20 more checkbox in my real program.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Im so damn stupid. Make the all check box first then single later.

```
 private class CheckBoxHandler implements ItemListener
    {
    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) 
    {
        if (chckbxNewCheckBox1.isSelected() && chckbxNewCheckBox2.isSelected())
        {
            checkboxcheck1 = 1;
            checkboxcheck2 = 1;

        }
        else if(chckbxNewCheckBox1.isSelected())
        {
            checkboxcheck1 = 1;

        }
        else if(chckbxNewCheckBox2.isSelected())
        {
            checkboxcheck2 = 1;

        }
    }
    }

  private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener
  {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
         if (checkboxcheck1 == 1 && checkboxcheck2 == 1)
         {
             textFieldSum.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
             textFieldSum1.setText(String.valueOf(counter1));
         }
         else if(checkboxcheck1 == 1)
            {
             textFieldSum.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
            }
         else if (checkboxcheck2 == 1)
         {
              textFieldSum1.setText(String.valueOf(counter1));
         }
         else
         {
            checkboxcheck1 = 0;
         }
    }   
  }
```